# Linux Mint 17 - Boot Up Mint Icon Becomes Purple Ubuntu Screen After Removing Packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon.

The first few times it booted up, the Mint icon was displayed while booting up.

I then removed some applications using the Software Manager (e.g. Thunderbird, etc) as well as some seemingly trivial ones (e.g. cowsay and fortune cookies, etc).

Subsequently when I booted up, the Mint icon no longer shows. Instead, there was the purple screen with the words "Ubuntu 14.04".

How can I get the Mint icon back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the dependent packages of what I removed, made some educated guesses, some trial and error, and found that the package needed for the icon is

**mint-artwork-common**

which is indirectly dependent on both fortune-mod and cowsay!